# C++ - copying from const char* to string

Tags: c++, string, copying

Is there a way to copy string from `const char*` to `string` in C++? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string s1;
    const char* pStr = "Sample Text";

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(pStr); i++)
        s1[i] = pStr[i];

    cout<<s1<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In my case `s1` turns out to be empty.

Comment: Why not just `s1 = pStr;`? `std::string` [has an `operator=` overload for `const char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D). The answers are correct you'd need to resize first to copy one at a time (or use `push_back` or `operator+=` to resize and append for each operation), but why do that work yourself?

Comment: Also, side-note: While some compilers may special case it to avoid the issue, by bog standard C/C++, `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(pStr); i++)` is going to recalculate the length of `pStr` over and over (once each time the condition is tested). Calculate it once outside the loop and save it to a variable and test against that if you must do something like this, or just use pointer arithmetic and stop when `*ptr` is the NUL character (so you scan the string only once, not 1-X times for the length, and one time for copying).

Comment: It's strange why you didn't simply try the obvious `s1 = pStr;` first, and then see what results you get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), the constructors of `std::basic_string` (the template class behind `std::string`), alternative (5):

```
const char* pStr = "Sample Text";
string s1(pStr);

cout<<s1<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

### C++11

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

string s1;
const char* pStr = "Sample Text";

std::copy(pStr, pStr + strlen(pStr), std::back_inserter(s1));
```

Another way:

```
string s1;
const char* pStr = "Sample Text";

s1.assign(pStr);
```

Comment: Why even default construct the string?

Comment: @NathanOliver that's what the OP has, you should ask him

Answer (score 1):

You should **either** initialize s1 to have a size equal to strlen(pStr) **or** just append each character to s1.

Initiating s1 with a specific size would be as the line of code given below.

```
string s1(strlen(pStr));
```

Similarly, appending each character would be as follows.

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(pStr); i++)
    s1.push_back(pStr[i]);
```

However, unless you have a specific reason to investigate each character, I would recommend *not using a loop* at all, and initiating s1 as follows.

```
string s1{ pStr };
```